# Notifications in i3 bar

Tags: arch-linux, i3, notifications

Until recently my notifications looked like described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371020/notify-osd-notifications-appear-unthemed-in-top-left-corner), but unlike the OP of the linked questions I really like this notification style.

[image: 1]

Since the last upgrade of my base OS (Arch) the style looks different and it seems as if dunst is now actually doing what it is supposed to do.

However, I prefer the plain style over fancy boxes. What mechanism allows me to have notifications as shown in the image above?

Answer (score 1):

You can configue dunst via the dunstrc file if you do not already have a config file for it you can create `~/.config/dunst/dunstrc` and change everything about it how and where the notification is displayed.  Or you can use a different notification daemon `twmn` is a very light weight notification daemo https://github.com/sboli/twmn but modifing dunst is pretty easy the default config has alot of comments that explain everything.  The default dunstrc is located at `/etc/dunst/dunstrc`.  If you don't have a dunstrc already just copy the default to the location I mentioned earlier in the post.